# Is it possible to allow the user to choose if they want to see the code in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I usually collaborate with people who is not interested in the underlying code of analyses. So usually I hide the code. But I'd like to allow the user to see the code if they want.

I have tried:

```
{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("ShowCode", label = "Do you want to see the code?",
              choices = c("TRUE", "FALSE"), selected = "FALSE")
)
ShowC <- renderText({input$ShowCode})

ShowC
```

In the next code chunk I set as options:

```
{r, echo = ShowC}

#Whatevercode
```

The first chunk properly allows the user to choose TRUE or FALSE, the second one shows the code or not depending on the option selected by default, but doesn't change with the user choice.

Comment: I think you want `{r, echo = input$ShowCode}`. But I don't know if this works, I rarely used Shiny in Rmarkdown.

Comment: Thanks. It gives as Error: Can't access reactive value 'ShowCode' outside of reactive consumer. Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?
If I try `{r, echo = observe(input$ShowCode)}` (or reactive) it runs, but chunk options are not reactive

Comment: This thread is the closest I've found, I think it's too much for me _:-D I can attach the code as a separate file... 
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2419

Comment: Why not just make the code of the project available out of channel, e.g. on GitHub, and then add a link to the project to the bottom of your document? That way if the reader is interested they can peruse the code in their own time.

In general it’s rarely useful to have a report interspersed with code, even though R Markdown encourages this as the default.

Comment: Probably this will be the best... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a chunk to display the code, you can display it in the Shiny app, in this way it is easy to show/hide with the help of `ConditionalPanel`. To display a stylish code, you can use the **monaco** package, or **aceEditor**, or **shinyAce**. Here is an example with **monaco**:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "2023-07-14"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

To learn more, see [Interactive Documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(monaco)
code <- '
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),
  
  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")
  
  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
'
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  checkboxInput("show", "Show code")
)
inputPanel(
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.show",
    monaco(
      contents = code,
      language = "r",
      width = "800px", height = "400px"
    )
  )
)
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),
  
  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")
  
  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

[image]

Comment: As it works, I accept it :-) but probably is best to have it in a different document. Thanks